# Why does Pandas DataFrame Resample change column Order

Tags: python, pandas

I have some Daily OHLC Data that I am resampling to Weekly using the function below, the Daily DataFrame columns are [u'Open', u'High', u'Low', u'Close', u'Volume']

```
def loadWeekly(symbol):
    df = loadDaily(symbol)

    ohlc_dict = {
    'Open':'first',
    'High':'max',
    'Low':'min',
    'Close':'last',
    'Volume':'sum'
    }

    return df.resample('W-Fri', how=ohlc_dict)
```

When I call the loadWeekly function the returned DataFrame columns are [u'High', u'Close', u'Volume', u'Open', u'Low']

Any idea what is causing this and how I can get it to keep original column order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because python dictionaries are unordered.  You could use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), but probably easiest to just re-order the results, with something like this.

```
order = df.columns
return df.resample('W-Fri', how=ohlc_dict)[order]
```